# Ajax-request to set a like/dislike in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

i'd like to make a like/dislike ability on my RoR application. How can i make it via Ajax-requests ?

dislike and like - are integer
how can i make an Ajax-request, than i can send the data of what i want to increment either "like"  or "dislike" counter in my methods

I have a table with posts :

## app/views/dashboard/view.html.erb

```
<table>
  <%if @post.count!=0%>
    <%@post.each do |p|%>
      <%if !p.text.nil?%>
      <tr>
       <td><b class="margin"><h4><%=p.text%></b></h4></td>
       <td>by <%=p.user.username%>&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
       <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up likeAction"><%= link_to p.like, dashboard_like_path, :remote => true, :id => 'likecount' %> </td>
       <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"><%= link_to p.dislike, dashboard_dislike_path, :remote => true, :id => 'dislikecount' %> </td>
      <%end%>
    <% end %>
  <%else%>
    There's no posts yet, but you can add <%=link_to "one", dashboard_posts_create_a_post_path%>
  <%end%>
</table>
```

My js file

```
#app/views/dashboard/view.js
$('#likecount').text(@post.like);
$('#dislikecount').text(@post.dislike);
```

my methods in controller :

```
def like
    @post.increment!(:like)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def dislike
    @post.increment!(:dislike)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

My dashboard.js in assets/javascripts

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("likeAction").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: dashboard_like_path,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(){
            $('#linkcount').text(data);
        }
        error: function(error){
           alert(error);
        }
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: This gem might be of use to you: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rails **remote => true** function for making ajax call. You can see more details [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).

Now answer of your question,

i. create link for like & dislike like:

```
<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"><%= link_to p.like, <link-of-like-path>, :remote => true, :id => 'likecount' %> </td>
<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"><%= link_to p.dislike, <link-of-dislike-path>, :remote => true, :id => 'dislikecount' %></td>
```

ii. Now in controller you'll receive Ajax request & you need to give response in js format. So your like method will be like:

```
def like
   @post.increment!(:like)
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
   end
end

def dislike
   @post.increment!(:dislike)
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
   end
end
```

iii. create (action_name).js.erb file to handle js response. In your case it will be like.js.erb file in app/view/posts folder. Here write js code to replace like/dislike count.

```
$('#likecount').text(@post.like);
$('#dislikecount').text(@post.like);
```

If you want to go with your current code, then you need to add json handler in controller as

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json {@post.like}
end
```

and then use ajax success to replace text of like as,

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("likeAction").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: path-to-like-function,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(){
            $('#linkcount').text(data);
        }
        error: function(error){
           alert(error);
        }
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your js file need to be be with your action name. So for like it will be 'app/views/dashboards/like.js.erb' and 'app/views/dashboards/dislike.js.erb'. As we are sending request in js format you need some response handler in js format. And by default it will look for file having same name as action. If you want to render different js file, mention that file name in 'format.js' block